# Handling uuid pk column in yii

Tags: yii

I'm using UUID's as PK in my tables. They're stored in a `BINARY(16)` MySQL column. I find that they're being mapped to `string` type in YII. The CRUD code I generate breaks down though, because these binary column types are being HTML encoded in the views. Example:

```
<?php echo 
        CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->usr_uuid), /* This is my binary uuid field */
        array('view', 'id'=>$data->usr_uuid)); ?>
```

To work around this problem, I overrode `afterFind()` and `beforeSave()` in my model where I convert the values to/from hex using `bin2hex` and `hex2bin` respectively. See [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32490-binary-string-as-primary-key-throws-error-in-cgridview/) for more details.

This takes care of the view problems.

However, now the search on PK when accessing a url of the form:

http://myhost.com/mysite/user/ec12ef8ebf90460487abd77b3f534404

results in `User::loadModel($id)` being called which in turn calls:

```
User::model()->findByPk($id);
```

This doesn't work since the SQL is being generated (on account of it being mapped to php `string` type) is

```
select ... where usr_uuid='EC12EF8EBF90460487ABD77B3F534404'
```

What would have worked is if I could, for these uuid fields change the condition to:

```
select ... where usr_uuid=unhex('EC12EF8EBF90460487ABD77B3F534404')
```

I was wondering how I take care of this problem cleanly. I see one possiblity - extend `CMysqlColumnSchema` and override the necessary methods to special case and handle binary(16) columns as uuid type.

This doesn't seem neat as there's no support for `uuid` natively either in php (where it is treated as string) or in mysql (where I have it as binary(16) column).

Does anyone have any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan using it within your own code then I'd create my own base AR class:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
  // ...
  public function findByUUID($uuid)
  {
    return $this->find('usr_uuid=unhex(:uuid)', array('uuid' => $uuid));
  }
}
```

If it's about using generated code etc. then customizing schema a bit may be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar. I'm giving it to you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to make working with uuid (binary(16)) columns using Yii/MySQL possible and efficient. I mention efficient, because I could have just made the column a CHAR(32) or (36) with dashes, but that would really chuck efficient out of the window.

I extended `CActiveRecord` and added a virtual attribute `uuid` to it. Also overloaded two of the base class methods `getPrimaryKey` and `setPrimaryKey`. With these changes most of Yii is happy.

```
class UUIDActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord 
{
    public function getUuid()
    {
        $pkColumn = $this->primaryKeyColumn;
        return UUIDUtils::bin2hex($this->$pkColumn);
    }

    public function setUuid($value)    
    {
        $pkColumn = $this->primaryKeyColumn;
        $this->$pkColumn = UUIDUtils::hex2bin($value);
    }

    public function getPrimaryKey()
    {
            return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function setPrimaryKey($value)        
    {
            $this->uuid = $value;
    }

    abstract public function getPrimaryKeyColumn();
}
```

Now I get/set UUID using this virtual attribute:

```
$model->uuid = generateUUID();  // return UUID as 32 char string without the dashes (-)
```

The last bit, is about how I search. That is accomplished using:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('bkt_user = unhex(:value)');
$criteria->params = array(':value'=>Yii::app()->user->getId()); //Yii::app()->user->getId() returns id as hex string
$buckets = Bucket::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

A final note though, parameter logging i.e. the following line in `main.php`:

```
'db'=>array(
    ...
    'enableParamLogging' => true,
    );
```

Still doesn't work, as once again, Yii will try to html encode binary data (not a good idea). I haven't found a workaround for it so I have disabled it in my config file.